# Regular expression matching http in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to return true for the following cases:

1. `http://anything`
2. `http:///anything` (It can have any number of "/")

But, it should return false for the following cases:

1. http://
2. http:/
3. http:
4. http
5. htt
6. ht
7. h
8. `http:///` (It can have any number of "/")

I tried the following, but it fails in some cases. Can anyone give some pointers.

```
(/^(f|ht)tps?:\/\//i.test(jQuery("base").attr("href")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:f|ht)tps?:\/{2,}[^\/].*
```

- `\/{2,}` will match 2 or more `/` in your input.
- `[^\/].*` after `\/{2,}` will make sure that input doesn't end with `http://` or `https:///`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kX8xC6/1)

Comment: You're right. Check my updated answer and demo link.

Comment: Thanks a ton !!! works like a charm and thanks for the explanations for better understanding !!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

var re = new RegExp("http://+[^/\\s][^\\s]*","g");

// To test a single do
// re.test(string)

output.innerHTML = input.innerHTML.match(re).join("\n");
```

```css
#output {
  background-color:#EEF5F9;
  padding:10px;
}
h2 {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-size:medium;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
pre {
  margin:0;
  padding:0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Inputs</h2>
<pre id="input">
    http://foo
    http:///bar
    http://foo-bar/baz
    http://
    http:/
    http:
    http
    htt
    ht
    h
    http:/// (It can have any number of "/")
</pre>

<h2>Matched</h2>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```